# dropping index in Azure SQL gives 'Cannot drop the index 'xyz', because it does not exist or you do not have permission'

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to delete some indexes from within SQL Azure - I receive ***Cannot drop the index 'xyz', because it does not exist or you do not have permission***

select * from sys.indexes shows the index, so I believe it is present

I'm the admin on the DB,  issuing the command via Visual Studio

any ideas?

Comment: SQL Azure does not allow to drop the clustered index, so that may be the cause, even though this usually gives a different error message. Can you post the `DROP INDEX` you're sending off?

Comment: Are you using a V11 database? If so, that version does not support heaps, so it restricts you from deleting the clustered index. I would highly recommend upgrading to V12 because this version does support heaps.

Comment: Since this got refreshed recently, the V11 servers no longer exist in SQL Azure.  Only the V12 edition now exists.  The question was based on the V11 architecture and this restriction is not there in current SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the syntax, in Azure SQL the correct way is

`DROP INDEX [index_name] on [table_name]` and not `DROP INDEX [table_name].[index_name]`

See [Error dropping index on SQL Azure database: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON' (user context = dbo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182973/error-dropping-index-on-sql-azure-database-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-o)