# Error dropping index on SQL Azure database: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON' (user context = dbo)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I have a database in SQL Azure and I am wanting to use a script to drop all the column store indexes.

I am connecting using SSMS using the SQL admin login of the SQL Server.

I am using this script:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'';
select @sql = @sql + N'DROP INDEX ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) + '.' + i.name + N' ON ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) + '.' + o.name + ';
'
FROM sys.indexes AS i INNER JOIN sys.tables AS o ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
where i.name is not null and o.name is not null and i.type_desc like '%COLUMN%'
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

An example statement:

```
DROP INDEX [dbo].[CCI_MyTable] ON [dbo].[MyTable];
```

When run, this generates error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

If I try just:

```
 DROP INDEX [dbo].[CCI_MyTable]
```

This generates error:

> Cannot drop the index 'dbo.CCI_MyTable', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

In SSMS, I can see the SQL SERVER admin user exists in the [master] database, but does not exist in the DATABASE I am working in.

Within this DATABASE, I am running as 'dbo':

```
SELECT USER_NAME()      -- DBO  
SELECT CURRENT_USER;    -- DBO
```

Shouldn't dbo have permissions to drop indexes?

**ASK:**
What is the proper way to go about this?  Do I need to add the admin user to this database?  If that user existed, and I connect with SSMS, would user_name() then be that user rather than dbo?

Comment: remove dbo from [dbo].[CCI_MyTable] and keep rest of script as it is

Comment: indexes are bound to table,tables are differentiated by schemas

Comment: It seems like preceding the INDEX name with dbo is the problem.  Many examples on the internet use that notation so not sure what my problem is.

Comment: The syntax is [`index_name ON <object>'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-index-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was preceding the index name with the schema (although, I swear many examples I've read do just that).

So the correct script syntax is:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'';
select @sql = @sql + N'DROP INDEX ' + i.name + N' ON ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) + '.' + o.name + ';
'
FROM sys.indexes AS i INNER JOIN sys.tables AS o ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
where i.name is not null and o.name is not null and i.type_desc like '%COLUMN%'
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```